# How to fix this git branch?

Tags: git, github

I am having some trouble to fix those branches:

[image]

Currently I am working in a branch `intercom-bridge` (originally the yellow line) that is a branch of `master`. In order to implement a new feature I created a branch `external-service-user` (the black line) from `intercom-bridge` and then when I merged this branch to `intercom-bridge` I got this result.

I think the problem is that I committed a change in the `intercom-bridge` before merging with the branch `external-service-user`.

What I want is to organize the commits in order to look that all the changes were made in a single branch. If possible to merge the black line (`external-service-user`) to the yellow line (`intercom-bridge`). It is possible to do that?

Comment: It's not clear from your picture what the problem is.  Can you explain more clearly what it is you want?  Also, replacing the existing image with one that shows all the branch labels you're discussing would help out.

Comment: @larsks I already update the image and question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C** is a branch that is exactly the same as **external-service-user** before you tried to merge master in it.

If you have trouble going to a state of a branch like `C`:
you could probably do something about it. First determine the commit that has triggered a merge, here it would be the 3rd yellow point from the left of the yellow line, to the right. Let's call this commit hash `3`, but you would have to replace with the actual hash in your history (thanks captain obvious hah).

```
git checkout 3
git checkout -b C
```

When you created a branch in `C` state:

```
git fetch
git checkout C
git rebase -p origin/master
```

And that should be enough. If conflicts appear, solve them then use `git add` with the concerned files, once they all are added to the index (check with git status -> they usually are described as "both modified" if you forgot one of them), use `git rebase --continue`.

Rebase strategy replays each commit you have ahead of the branch you are trying to rebase from, so don't panic if a file appears to have a conflict several times, just repeat the steps I described above until the conflicts are all solved.

Also `-p` option (p for preserve) is important so that any previous merge from master doesn't get rebased too in the process.

Comment: I updated the picture. I think I understood your explanation, the problem is that in C state the original branch was the `intercom-bridge`. And I was trying to merge the `external-user-service` into `intercom-bridge`. The solution is the same?

Comment: Basically yes, a rebase is a way to put your commits above a base, without an additional commit (since it was replayed from start, it is not needed)

Comment: I can't understand why when I merged the `external-service` branch to the `intercom-bridge` branch the result tree was that in the figure (the black line was created from the yellow). Because looks like that I tried to merge with the `master` and I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have single branch with all your changes you can simply pull your content (branches) to the desired branch

```
# checkout master branch
git checkout master

# merge all the desired branches into master
git merge external-user-service intercom-bridge
```

Now master contains all the changes made in all the 3 branches.

---

#### Using `cherry-pick`

`git cherry-pick` allow you to pick any commits you made in any branch to any other branch. In your case you can simply checkout master branch and then `cherry-pick` all the commits from any branch that you wish (`cherry-pick` support ranges so you can specify start and end commit instead of list all the commits)

This way you can control the way your commits will appear in the merged branch.

for example:

```
git cherry-pick ebe6942..905e279
```